# Gremlin Neptune query similar users based on common ratings count

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

From the following graph in the Tickerpop recipes:

```
  g.addV("user").property("name", "alice").as("u1").
  addV("user").property("name", "jen").as("u2").
  addV("user").property("name", "dave").as("u3").
  addV("movie").property("name", "the wild bunch").as("m1").
  addV("movie").property("name", "young guns").as("m2").
  addV("movie").property("name", "unforgiven").as("m3").
  addE("friend").from("u1").to("u2").
  addE("friend").from("u1").to("u3").
  addE("like").from("u2").to("m1").
  addE("like").from("u2").to("m2").
  addE("like").from("u3").to("m2").
  addE("like").from("u3").to("m3")
```

How can i query friends of a specific user in descending order of how many common movies they have liked? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some more edges to the graph to make the results more interesting.

```java
  g.addV("user").property("name", "alice").as("u1").
  addV("user").property("name", "jen").as("u2").
  addV("user").property("name", "dave").as("u3").
  addV("movie").property("name", "the wild bunch").as("m1").
  addV("movie").property("name", "young guns").as("m2").
  addV("movie").property("name", "unforgiven").as("m3").
  addE("friend").from("u1").to("u2").
  addE("friend").from("u1").to("u3").
  addE("friend").from("u2").to("u3").
  addE("friend").from("u2").to("u1").
  addE("like").from("u2").to("m1").
  addE("like").from("u2").to("m2").
  addE("like").from("u3").to("m2").
  addE("like").from("u3").to("m3").
  addE("like").from("u1").to("m1").
  addE("like").from("u1").to("m2")
```

We can then, for example, find Jen and collect the movies Jen likes and then find Jen's friends and count the number of movies they each like in common.

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has('name','jen').as('jen').
......2>   sideEffect(out('like').store('movies')).
......3>   out('friend').
......4>   group().
......5>     by("name").
......6>     by(out('like').where(within('movies')).count())    


==>[dave:1,alice:2]
```

You could also go one step further and order the results in either ascending or descending order.

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has('name','jen').as('jen').
......2>   sideEffect(out('like').store('movies')).
......3>   out('friend').
......4>   group().
......5>     by("name").
......6>     by(out('like').where(within('movies')).count()).
......7>     order(local).
......8>       by(values,desc)  

==>[alice:2,dave:1]
```

**UPDATED** to add an example where other information is part of the result.

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has('name','jen').as('jen').
......2>   sideEffect(out('like').store('movies')).
......3>   out('friend').
......4>   group().
......5>     by(valueMap(true)).
......6>     by(out('like').where(within('movies')).count()).
......7>     order(local).
......8>     by(values,asc)    

==>[[id:61353,label:user,name:[dave]]:1,[id:61349,label:user,name:[alice]]:2]
```

To omit the counts from the result

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has('name','jen').as('jen').
......2>   sideEffect(out('like').store('movies')).
......3>   out('friend').
......4>   group().
......5>     by(valueMap(true)).
......6>     by(out('like').where(within('movies')).count()).
......7>     order(local).
......8>     by(values,asc).
......9>   select(keys)  

==>[[id:61353,label:user,name:[dave]],[id:61349,label:user,name:[alice]]]
```

Comment: suppose i want the response to contain all properties of the user vertices - let's say user also has a string property called "avatarUrl" in addition to "username" - how can i render this along with the username in the response? do i create another sideEffect? basically, i want to return an array of user dictionaries with each dictionary containing all the key/value pairs of the user rather than the single k/v pair in the example above. i still want to order the results by the count of common ratings, but i do not need to render the numeric count.

Comment: so basically [{"username": "alice", "avatarUrl": "/sdjhfgsg/test.jpg"}, {"username": "dave", "avatarUrl": "/djhsfghsg/test1.jpg"}]

Comment: You can change the `group` to use a `valueMap` - I'll update the answer with and example. Note that `valueMap` can take a list of the properties you want included as parameters.

Comment: If you don't want to include the actual count in the result you can just select the `keys` from the map created by `group`

Comment: Thanks again, Kelvin. You're a huge help!

Comment: @kevin-lawrence - i have the results that i need now, thanks again. one last question on this. the results from this query 'g.V('a2661f57-8aa7-4e5c-9c89-55cf9b7e4cf8').as('self')
.sideEffect(out('rated').store('movies'))
.out('friended')
.group()
.by(valueMap(true).by(unfold()))
.by(out('rated').where(within('movies')).count())
.order(local)
.by(values,desc)
.unfold()
.select(keys)'

Comment: return results in this format: {<T.id: 1>: 'fdc45bd3-be08-4716-b20f-b4f04987c5e0', <T.label: 4>: 'user', 'username': 'elin102dev', 'name': 'elin obrien', 'avatarUrl': 'public/avatars/fdc45bd3-be08-4716-b20f-b4f04987c5e0.jpg'}. how can i project or change the T.id and T.label keys in the results to just "id" and "label"?

Comment: You can still select from the map using `T.id` and `T.label` as the key names which might be the simplest thing to do.